# Nested list manipulation, double forloop needed?

Tags: python, nested-loops, nested-lists

So I want to change this nested(list) lets call it X

```
[['What if?', ' 2014', ' Randall Munroe'], ['Thing Explainer', ' 2015', ' Randall Munroe'], ['Alan Turing: The Enigma', ' 2014', ' Andrew Hodges']]
```

To This nested(list) lets it Y

```
[['What if', 'Thing Explainer', 'Alan Turing: The Enigma'], [ 2014,2015,2014], ['Randall Munroe, Randall Munroe, 'Andrew Hodges']]
```

The first term in Y is the first item in the ith term in X.

```
['What if', 'Thing Explainer', 'Alan Turing: The Enigma']
```

The second term in Y is the second item in the ith term in X

```
['Randall Munroe, Randall Munroe, 'Andrew Hodges']
```

Can anyone share there thought process and solutions in python?

Comment: `map(list, zip(*X))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
map (list, zip(*[['What if?', ' 2014', ' Randall Munroe'], ['Thing Explainer', ' 2015', ' Randall Munroe'], ['Alan Turing: The Enigma', ' 2014', ' Andrew Hodges']]))
```

This will do you exactly what you need.

Comment: But I want a nested listed returned if I do it your way this happens

         a  = map (list, zip(*[['What if?', ' 2014', ' Randall Munroe'], ['Thing Explainer', ' 2015', ' Randall Munroe'], ['Alan Turing: The Enigma', ' 2014', ' Andrew Hodges']]))

        print(a)
        <map object at 0x101e0f438>

Comment: Just converted it to list object, thank you !!!

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the built-in `zip` function in Python.

```
>>> zip(*[['What if?', ' 2014', ' Randall Munroe'], ['Thing Explainer', ' 2015', ' Randall Munroe'], ['Alan Turing: The Enigma', ' 2014', ' Andrew Hodges']])
```

There is more documentation located at https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: You would need to unpack the arguments to the `zip` function i.e. `zip(*your_list)`.

Comment: Yeah, I still want to return a nested loop

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what packages you want to/don't want to use. But `numpy` can do this quite easily:

```
import numpy as np
dat = [['What if?', ' 2014', ' Randall Munroe'], ['Thing Explainer', ' 2015', ' Randall Munroe'], ['Alan Turing: The Enigma', ' 2014', ' Andrew Hodges']]
np.array(dat).T.tolist()
# [['What if?', 'Thing Explainer', 'Alan Turing: The Enigma'],
#  [' 2014', ' 2015', ' 2014'],
#  [' Randall Munroe', ' Randall Munroe', ' Andrew Hodges']]
```

Comment: Sorry can't import anything :S